# 'Newest' sort order for answers is gone?

Tags: support, sorting

MO has a 'newest' sort order, dual to 'oldest' and different from 'active'. M.SE used to have it too, I think, but it is now gone? Why?

Comment: I had to solve a captcha to ask this question. **EVERY SINGLE TIME** I post a question in this meta I am asked to solve a captcha. Somehow, I have stopped believing claims about 10%s of this and 1% of that... So let's have this, once and for all: *Yes, I am a robot* and *I can solve captchas*. Can the site get over that?

Comment: Mariano, are you still a robot, or did you go through one of them fancy "reverse fossilization" processes and became human?

Answer (score 3):

Here's Jeff Atwood's reason:

[Bring back the 'oldest' sort order for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers/75301#75301)

Here's a feature request to bring it back (alongside the new "oldest" tab):

[Answer sort order: oldest *and* newest?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75327/answer-sort-order-oldest-and-newest)

Comment: In so far as answers are concerned, I agree with ChrisF on the second link: not much is lost from not having a newest tab on answers. And I am generally more interested in recent changes (for answers) than for newest original post dates.

Answer (score 1):

Click first on [Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions). The "Newest" tab will then appear.

(Or perhaps you meant for answers? Yeah, I don't see it either.)